# Open Excel Workbook with java

Tags: java, excel

I have an *UI* that can ask for the path of the `excel sheets`. But the moment I give those paths to a workbook to open or do something with them, all possible kind of exception start to happen because of the need of from create to handle `exceptions`.

I use the `APACHE POI library` and the `Commons IO library` because they are required to start the project.

Here´s some of the code I am talking about:

```
//Start Button
JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
startButton.setBounds(100, 150, buttonWidth, height);
panel.add(startButton);
startButton.addActionListener(e -> {
String sourceFilePath = filePath1TextField.getText();
String targetFilePath = filePath2TextField.getText();
String savePath = savePathTextField.getText();

Workbook sourceWorkbook;
Workbook targetWorkbook;

try {
//Pfade zu den Excel-Dokumenten festlegen
sourceWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(sourceFilePath));
targetWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(targetFilePath));
```

It should just `initialize the workbooks` and go on to the next steps because these are the only problems I have.

,But instead of doing that all these exceptions get triggered for no reason at all, even though I `debbuged` all of the code for mistakes.

It only happens when I try to create a new workbook and at that point it just stops and doesn't compile the code below it. Here are the `exceptions:`

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
    at org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:43)
    at 
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic.valueOf(FileMagic.java:209)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:222)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185)
    at GUI.lambda$new$4(GUI.java:100)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:262)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
   ... 41 more
```

Comment: "all possible kind of exception start to happen because of the need of from create to handle exceptions" what do you mean? Can you please [edit] your question to clarify? What exceptions are you getting and at what point of the code?